# How to get all keys that have the same name and put them in a separate dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

Let's say I have a huge dictionary of values. (here is the values. mind the formatting [it's not detailed)](https://gist.github.com/master98ofu/dcae7d03722343d5c3182e59f69db6a9)

Anyway, there is multiple keys with the same name, however they are in different locations. All I really need is to get the values from said keys and add them together: e.g. totalSessionsLost and totalSessionsWon

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.

Comment: Post a small example with your best coding attempt.  Follow the guidelines per input and output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of a solution that can read your `j.json` file and return a `dict` with the sum of all the keys inside sets of your file:

**PS:**

This kind of code can sum the data of a file with this kind of format:

`{...,key1:[{..., key2:{...keys_of_elements_to_sum...}}, {..., key3:{...keys_of_elements_to_sum...}}, ...]}`

So, here is the code:

```
from ast import literal_eval
from itertools import groupby

def get_sum_of_repeated_keys(data):
    keys = []
    for k in data:
        # check the key is a list
        if isinstance(data[k], list):
            # if the key is a list
            # We'll parse all the list's elements
            for j in data[k]:
                # if the elements of the previous list
                # are dicts
                if isinstance(j, dict):
                    # parse the keys of the list's dicts
                    for m in j:
                        # If the elements of the previous list's dicts are dicts
                        if isinstance(j[m], dict):
                            # Appends the items to the list called keys
                            keys += j[m].items()

    # return a dict with the sum of the groupped elements by key
    return {k:sum(k[1] for k in list(v)) for k, v in groupby(sorted(keys), lambda x: x[0])}

# Read the JSON file and convert it into a python dict
with open('j.json', 'r') as f:
    a = f.read().rstrip("\n")
    # This code uses 'literal_eval'
    # because your input file isn't a valid JSON file
    data = literal_eval(a)

# The final result
final = get_sum_of_repeated_keys(data)
# list the keys of the final result
# print(final.keys())
# Print an elements using its key
print("Total sessions won:", final['totalSessionsWon'])
print("Total sessions lost:", final['totalSessionsLost'])
```

Output:

```
Total sessions won: 132
Total sessions lost: 122
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it:

```
subdicts = huge_dict_of_values['champions']
keys = subdicts[0]['stats'].keys() # assuming that no dict has keys that this one doesn't have, for simplicity 
totals = {key: sum([subdict['stats'][key] for subdict in subdicts] for key in keys])}
```

output:

```
>>> totals
{'totalPhysicalDamageDealt': 16313032, 'totalTurretsKilled': 316, 'totalSessionsPlayed': 254, 'totalAssists': 2208, 'totalDamageDealt': 31926510, 'totalQuadraKills': 2, 'totalPentaKills': 0, 'mostSpellsCast': 0, 'totalDoubleKills': 178, 'maxChampionsKilled': 450, 'totalDeathsPerSession': 1842, 'totalSessionsWon': 132, 'totalGoldEarned': 3064958, 'totalTripleKills': 26, 'totalChampionKills': 1730, 'maxNumDeaths': 485, 'totalMinionKills': 36376, 'totalMagicDamageDealt': 12982770, 'mostChampionKillsPerSession': 450, 'totalUnrealKills': 0, 'totalDamageTaken': 5812772, 'totalSessionsLost': 122, 'totalFirstBlood': 0}
>>>
```

In general, though, when you have dictionaries nested like this you probably would be better off with an object-oriented representation. It looks like there are several layers of semantics here, and it'd be a lot easier to deal with them if you were to give them names and define their relations more explicitly

This would also allow you to write code at each layer to handle this sort of reporting, which would be easier to read, test, and maintain